# How do I display a dashboard in Azure Devops that shows Build metrics

Tags: azure-devops

I'm creating a Pipeline in Azure Devops and I want to display a dashboard that shows build metrics, such as the number of build warnings.

How do I extract this information? I'm building on multiple platforms using CMake and am using the `Bash` task to run cmake build commands, so these would be per-compiler warnings, eg number of warnings in Clang, warnings in VC++ 2017 etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any build-in widget in dashboard to handle this.

You could try to built a customized analytics widget, a sample for your reference: [Create an Analytics widget for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/example-analytics-widget?view=azure-devops)

To fetch the metrics for a build pipeline/definition, you could use Rest API to handle this:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/metrics?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

More details take a look at this tutorial--[Metrics - Get Definition Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/metrics/get%20definition%20metrics?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Besides, you could also use or refer some 3rd-party extension in marketplace, such as this: *[Build Metrics Widget](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AbhinavKhanna.vsts-extensions-dashboard-build-metrics-widget)*